# how to customize xcode binding?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I want to customize save all command shortcut to shift+cmd+s, but I can't change it, I don't know why?![image]

Comment: It's because they change with the parent command ("Save") Shortcut.

Comment: thank you,could you answer the question? I'll accept it